# Android: SimpleExoPlayer crashing without exception on Pixel 4

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to play a video in a popup window in my app using `SimpleExoPlayer`. The video plays fine on all devices except for Pixel 4 where it causes a crash without any exception. The only error that I can see in the logs related to the crash *(after selecting No Filters in log in Android Studio)* is the following

```
2022-03-23 16:14:42.329 1081-19294/? E/QC2Buf: allocate: failed to alloc graphic block w(1088)/h(2352)/f(7fa30c06)/usage(20010000)
2022-03-23 16:14:42.329 1081-19294/? E/QC2V4l2Codec: [avcD_44] Error during buffer allocation
2022-03-23 16:14:42.329 1081-19294/? E/QC2Buf: allocate: failed to alloc graphic block w(1088)/h(2352)/f(7fa30c06)/usage(20010000)
2022-03-23 16:14:42.329 1081-19294/? E/QC2V4l2Codec: [avcD_44] Error during buffer allocation
2022-03-23 16:14:42.329 1081-19294/? E/QC2Buf: allocate: failed to alloc graphic block w(1088)/h(2352)/f(7fa30c06)/usage(20010000)
2022-03-23 16:14:42.329 1081-19294/? E/QC2V4l2Codec: [avcD_44] Error during buffer allocation
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? Thanks!